# Python hangman function

Tags: python

I have a function in hangman that is suppose to take the letters guessed and match it up against the word. Here's the function:

```
def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
x=len(secretWord)-1
y=0
letter=lettersGuessed[:]
while y<=x: 
    first=secretWord[y]
    if first in letter:
        return " " + first + " " + str(getGuessedWord(secretWord[1:], lettersGuessed[:]))
    else:
        return " _ " + str(getGuessedWord(secretWord[1:], lettersGuessed[:]))
```

The function is returning

" _  p  p  _  e None"

I want to get rid of the None at the end. I'm guessing I have an extra iteration. However, can anyone help me with not running that extra iteration at the end? Thanks.

Comment: what did you put as input to the function ?

Comment: please fix indentation

Comment: You have no iterations. You have a recursive function with bits of a while loop used to fake a for loop, which actually does nothing (except execute its body once).

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578984-hangman/?in=lang-python Here is a hangman that I made before. You can check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line at the end of your function :

```
return ''
```

When the guessedwords is an empty list, the function has nothing to return, so it returns None. But you can fix that by returning the empty character. In fact, that should be the base case of your recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

`def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    lst= ''
    for e in secretWord:
        if e in lettersGuessed:
            lst += e 
        else:
            lst += '_'
    return lst`

This passed all cases.